# Cygwin git passing wrong path to my editor for commit messages

Tags: git, cygwin

I'm using git under cygwin but it's not passing the correct path to my editor for commit messages.

I'm working in a test repository located on my drive at:

```
d:\X\git\myproject
```

in the cygwin terminal it shows this path as:

```
/cygdrive/d/X/git/myproject
```

When I commit without the -m flag (so that it opens up my editor for me to enter a message), my editor tries to write a file to the wrong path:

```
d:\cygdrive\d\x\git\myproject\.git\commit_editmsg
```

*note the addition of "\cygdrive\d"*

How can I make git pass the windows path (rather than the cygwin/unix path) to my editor?

Comment: Interesting question- Cygwin's path handling has vexed others as well as myself!  May I assume you're trying to open a Windows based editor as opposed to a Linux-ish terminal editor?  I've not had problems with the latter.

Comment: @rholmes - I am. It's an emacs clone for windows called Epsilon. After posting this, I found that epsilon actually has a setting to handle cygwin style paths, which thankfully lets me use it! But am still really curious how you'd do this in other editors...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

cygwin has a utility called `cygpath` which can be used to convert between cygwin and native Windows file paths.  For instance:

```
$ cygpath --windows /cygdrive/d/X/git/myproject
D:\X\git\myproject
```

We're going to create a script which uses this utility to convert the path before passing it to your editor.  We'll use emacs as an example, assuming it is installed at `C:\emacs`.  Create a file called `~/bin/git-editor.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
/cygdrive/c/emacs/bin/emacsclientw.exe $(cygpath --windows "${1}")
```

(since this is Windows, we don't need to set the executable flag on this file)

Now, set your git editor to point to this script:

```
$ git config --global core.editor "~/bin/git-editor.sh"
```

Comment: oh sweet, super helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Figured out how to do this using sublime editor and not having to resort to external scripts. `git config --global core.editor '/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/subl.exe --new-window --wait \`cygpath --windows ${1}\` && set -`

Comment: In case it wasn't obvious, you can test all of the above is working by typing git config -e.  If your config file is opened in your editor of choice you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

```sh
#!/bin/dash -e
if [ "$1" ]
then k=$(cygpath -w "$1")
elif [ "$#" != 0 ]
then k=
fi
Notepad2 ${k+"$k"}
```

1. If no path, pass no path
2. If path is empty, pass empty path
3. If path is not empty, convert to Windows format.

Then I set these variables:

```c
export EDITOR=notepad2.sh
export GIT_EDITOR='dash /usr/local/bin/notepad2.sh'
```

1. EDITOR allows script to work with Git
2. GIT_EDITOR allows script to work with [Hub commands](//hub.github.com)

[Source](//github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/tree/2973070/editor)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Cygwin git would not pass the correct path to sublime 3 (It would not include the cygwin64 folder) I created the git-editor.sh folder, this is what I put in it:

```
#!/bin/sh
 /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/subl.exe $(cygpath --windows "${1}") -w
```

Then made this .sh file my core.editor